# How can I create a List with foreach and add items to radiobuttonlist alphabetical

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm getting the Text and the key values from Umbraco and works 100%, but in this way I can't order the list I get. The site will have different languages and I need the items to be ordered  on the `radiobuttonlist` by value (which means by language) and not by the key in Umbraco.
 Is it possible?

```
foreach (umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem d2 in d1.Children)
{
    translation = "";
    translation = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem(d2.key).Value(lang);

    ListItem list; //start a list

    list = new ListItem(translation, d2.key); //save each item on it

    rbl_items.Items.Add(list); //add them to my radiobuttonlist
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add each element to a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) first within the `foreach`.  You can then bind the `RadioButtonlist` to this **SortedList**, as shown in [this article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/2900/bind-radiobuttonlist-through-sortedlist).

```
SortedList list= new SortedList();

foreach (umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem d2 in d1.Children)
{
    translation = "";
    translation = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Dictionary.DictionaryItem(d2.key).Value(lang);

    list.Add(translation, d2.key);
}

//bind to RadioButtonList 
RadioButtonList1.DataSource = list;
RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "Key";
RadioButtonList1.DataTextField="Value";
RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you sir, couldn't ask for a better and faster answer ! You are the man !